# Pan to location given lat,long in d3

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

D3 is relatively very new to me. I have been working around it I have a list of select dropdown where I can have the lat and long. On click the map should pan to the location ?

I am using d3 geo to render the map and not google maps or bing maps

Any suggestions ?

```
<select id="SeaList">
    <option value="119.77,-7.69,-110.41,57.25">North Pacific Ocean</option>
    <option value="153.48,-58.62,-70,7.10">South Pacific Ocean</option>
    <option value="-116.56,-1.39,13.34,60.59">North Atlantic Ocean</option>
    <option value="-89.62,-56.74,40.27,8.59">South Atlantic Ocean</option>
    <option value="19.53,-52.31,149.43,16.15">Indian Ocean</option>
    <option value="179.97,-84.5,79.78,-17.58">Southern Ocean</option>
    <option value="-22.35,22.97,-122.55,85.03">Arctic Ocean</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why not `.transition()` and `.attr('transform', \`translate(${lat}, ${long})\`)`

Comment: how would I write it ?